# uncaught error in js promise in react/redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, es6-promise

I am trying to get some data using this code

```
import mainAPI from '../api'

export const sendActions = () => async dispatch => {
    const response = await  mainAPI.get('/posts')
    dispatch({ type : "FETCH_POSTS",payload :response }) 
}
```

I am getting below error message in the console

> createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with
>   status code 404
>       at createError (createError.js:17)
>       at settle (settle.js:19) . 
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
>   this is my api code

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default axios.create({mainAPI: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'})
```

If anyone knows tell me how to resolve

Comment: The 404 error suggests that your API endpoint (/posts) doesn't exist.

Comment: The error means the ``/posts`` api is not found. Please check ``/posts`` api.

Comment: @Kei  I am getting api from a dummy server please check i added api code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have added baseURL, I have added a diffrent name thats why it was showing localhost

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default axios.create({baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'})
```